# Firebase write failed but completion handler didn't return error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This code has been running stably for about a year.
However in one instance recently updateChildValues did not write userDetails to the database but the else block (user profile created successfully) was still executed leading to a user profile that just contained value result.token at the key fcm-token.
If the ref.updateChildValues write is successful a profile is created with the contents of userDetails and the FCM token.

What circumstances could have caused this?

```
let userDetails: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["userName" : chosenName, "user-level" : BASIC, "email-addr" : emailAddr, ACC_CREATE_DATE_STR : timeStamp, ACC_LAST_ACTIVITY_STR : timeStamp]    
ref.updateChildValues(userDetails, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
             if let err = error {
                 let createAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please try again\n\(err.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: .alert)
                 createAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Got it", style: .default, handler: nil))
                 self.present(createAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
             } else {
                 // user profile created successfully
                 InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (result, error) in
                     if let error = error {
                         print("Error fetching FCM token: \(error)")
                     } else if let result = result {
                        ref.child("fcm-token").setValue(result.token)
                     }
                     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                   })
                 }
               })
```

Comment: please add the code for userDetails

Comment: Are you sure that the data being written to the database is actually different? I mean, the code is not producing an error, so the write must be working.

Comment: @DavidThorn In this instance the contents of userDetails were not written to the database but the FCM token was.  With this code I don't understand how this can happen.

Comment: @DavidLintin userDetails dictionary added.

Comment: Can you clarify what a *corrupt user profile* means? Was data stored in a child that you were not expecting? Can you show what the data should have been and what it was? Suppose you've never had a BASIC user so that var was defined at "test type" so when the data was written you ended up with 'corrupted data' because it wrote "test type" to a child node- that would have simply been a coding error. Can you clarify what you're asking and what the actual issue is?

Comment: @Jay I have updated question to make it clearer.  The data was stored at the expected child.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code and if the child node *fcm-value* was written to, then the userDetails write did not have an error. All that means is that something was written to whatever ref is/was and it could have been an empty string. There's not enough information in the question to formulate an answer since we don't know what ref is or was and if all of the child values in the dictionary were actually populated

Comment: @jay thanks for your continued interest.
userName is from a text field which cannot be nil.

Comment: Nil is not the same as "", and if you write "" to a node, the node will not exist.

Comment: @jay
BASIC is a global constant string "basic"
The 2 timestamp keys are set by let timeStamp = [".sv": "timestamp"].
ref is obtained from my database reference for users with user ref being created using authUser.user.uid - ref = USER_REF.child(authUser.user.uid)

Comment: it cannot be "" or nil

Comment: I understand but you're missing what I was saying. We cannot troubleshoot those issues - only you can. We don't know if they are nil, "" or something else. We also don't know what `ref` is or if it's pointing to the right node. That code works and will work as is, every time as long as the data you're feeding it is correct and the rules allow for writing (with no error, that's going to be the case).

Comment: I'll have write it down to experience and monitor the database.
Even if I have allowed userName to be nil somehow BASIC is a global constant, let BASIC = "basic" so will always have a value.